# ios: Done and Cancel do not work on the second app tutorial at apple tut site

Tags: ios4

Version 4.3.2 of XCODE.
This is causing me no end of headaches trying to figure out how to do the tutorial. I have checked the code against their code and it looks right. I downloaded someones else's copy and it works but with my copy done and cancel do not work.
AddSightingViewController.m code looks like this

```
#import "AddSightingViewController.h"
@implementation AddSightingViewController

...
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [[self delegate] addSightingViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [[self delegate] addSightingViewControllerDidFinish:self name:self.birdNameInput.text location:self.locationInput.text];
}
...
```

And debug checkpoints on these lines work correctly 
However in BirdsMasterViewController.m I have the following code:

```
#import "BirdsMasterViewController.h"
#import "BirdsDetailViewController.h"
#import "BirdSightingDataController.h"
#import "BirdSighting.h"
#import "AddSightingViewController.h"
@interface BirdsMasterViewController () <AddSightingViewControllerDelegate>
@end
@implementation BirdsMasterViewController
@synthesize dataController = _dataController;

...

- (void)addSightingViewControllerDidCancel:(AddSightingViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)addSightingViewControllerDidFinish:(AddSightingViewController *)controller name:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location {
    if ([name length] || [location length]) {
        [self.dataController addBirdSightingWithName:name location:location];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


...
```

and debug checkpoints on these lines never stop the program on my code (but do on the downloaded code). 
What in the heck am I missing to get this to work.